# core data in storage array attribute or work with files or relationship entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to work for a long time with the core data.
And I read a lot of tutorials about this and i asked a lot of questions.

Finally I started to work on core data
Through this guide:   **www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/**

And now I'm stuck!
I want to create the kind of attribute, array.
And was told me it's a not a good way to store array about attribute.
These work with a relationship.

But the problem here.
If you look at the guide, it does not create files (classes) entities
And all the other guides. Yes creating files, so they do not help me so   much because I do not have my entity files.

Is there a way to create the kind of relationship that behaves like array to one attribute, without me having to make file creating entities?
Because of my project is already very big.

Comment: I really do not understand that Q. I.e.: What is an "array attribute"?

Comment: For example, I have an entity named person, and I want the person to be many children
The problem is that I have a lot of person so I have to create a kind of array on entity

Comment: You can simply create the "NSManagedObject subclass" class files in Xcode: Select one or more entity in the Core Data model inspector and choose "Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass ..."

Comment: As Martin R said, you can create a subclass of your NSManagedObject i.e.. Person and than create instances of Person like Person *person1, Person *person2 etc or you can iterate over Person in loop. Doing this way will allow searching of relations and attribute of Person Entity.

Comment: As I understand, you don't want any entityClasses (aka subclasses of NSManagedObject) in your code? You can use CoreData with NSManagedObjects directly for all fetches and get the attributes via  key value. If you want a person to have many children, you have to model this as a one to many relationship. As a result you will get a NSSet for the key children on the entity person.

Comment: this is the problem ! i don't want create a subclass if i do this i need to fix all my project from start ! i need a way without create a subclass to NSManageObject !

Comment: Yedy , Thank you for understanding   but i don't how to to this i nedd Example like short code

Comment: Maby this will help: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-21505

Comment: You did some tutorials and don't know how to model a 1:n relationship?

Comment: why don't storing array on entity ? what the problem whit this way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason people don't recommend using arrays as attributes for CoreData entities is this: the array has to be converted to raw data to store it to the persistentStore, and then has to be converted back when the object is read from the store.  This has the potential to be slow, and the raw data could become "big".  Importantly, because the attribute is stored as raw data, you cannot fetch a subset of the stored objects using a predicate that depends on the contents of the array attribute.  So for example, you cannot (easily) fetch "only objects for which the array has only 1 member".

So, people recommend using a relationship.  I would strongly recommend that you do create subclasses; it will make your life so much easier if you do.  But it is possible to use relationships *without* subclassing.  Suppose you have a `Person` entity (with `name` and `dateOfBirth` attributes) and a `Course` entity (with just a `name` attribute).

Assume each `Person` can attend only one `Course`, but each `Course` can attended by several people.  You would create a to-many relationship from `Course` to `Person`, and name it something like `attendees`.  The inverse relationship would be `to-one` named something like `course`.  The model would thus look like this:

[image]

You are familiar with accessing attribute values using `valueForKey` and `setValue:forKey:`, eg. for a string attribute:

```
// Get...
NSString *myPersonName = [myPerson valueForKey:@"name"];
// Set...
[myPerson setValue:@"John Doe" forKey:@"name"];
```

Use the same methods to get/set relationships.  For a `to-one` relationship, the value you get/set will be an `NSManagedObject`:

```
// Get...
NSManagedObject *personCourse = [myPerson valueForKey:@"course"];
// Set...
[myPerson setValue:myCourse forKey:@"course"];
```

For `to-many` relationships, things get slightly more complicated.  Because a `Course` can have many `attendees`, the value you get/set is an `NSSet`:

```
// Get...
NSSet *myCourseAttendees = [myCourse valueForKey:@"attendees"];
for (NSManagedObject *person in myCourseAttendees) {
    NSLog(@"Attendee's name is %@", [person valueForKey:@"name"];
}
// Set...
NSSet *newAttendees = [NSSet setWithObjects:newPerson1, newPerson2, nil];
[myCourse setValue:newAttendees forKey:@"attendees"];
```

That's all well and good, but sometimes you just want to add/remove one attendee:

```
NSMutableSet *attendees = [myCourse mutableSetValueForKey:@"attendees"];
[attendees removeObject:myPerson];
[attendees addObject:myNewPerson];
```

So, managing `to-one` relationships is far easier than `to-many`.  Here's the good news: if your relationship has an inverse, whenever you modify it, CoreData will automatically update the inverse relationship for you.  So if you have a `to-many` relationship with a `to-one` inverse, just use the `to-one`.  Put another way, it's easier to use:

```
[myPerson setValue:newCourse forKey:@"course"];
```

than:

```
NSMutableSet *attendees = [newCourse mutableSetValueForKey:@"attendees"];
[attendees addObject:myPerson];
```

Both achieve the same thing.

Now, as others have pointed out elsewhere, you might in fact want a `Person` to be able to attend many different `Courses`.  In that case, both the relationship and its inverse will be `to-many`, and you're stuck using the mutable set methods.

Comment: Wow man, thank you, I did not expect someone to help me like you did,
I would try it, thanks again!

Comment: I do not know how to thank you. It works great!.
I finally know how to work with the relationship.
Thank you Thank you Thank you !