# Saving a collection of data with a one -> may relationship in core data swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity, persistence

I have a one to many relationship like this:
[image: core data bullshit]

The aim is to have a list with a relationship to a collection of items on that list. Another stack overflow post has told me that I need this sort of relationship to store a list of items, but I don't know how to add items to a specific list. Nor do I know how to save them.

Any advice, code examples or tutorials would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34143362/3985749) runs through handling relationships.  It's in Objective C but the principles are the same in Swift.  The related question specifically did not want to use NSManagedObject subclasses, but I would recommend you do.

Answer (score 1):

First created your "List" object , then you need to create "ItemList" objects , add them to your "List" object and save:

```
//Create List (if you didn't created it already).    
List *yourListObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedContext];

//Create as many ListItems as you need
ItemList *item1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemList" inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedContext];

ItemList *item2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemList" inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedContext];

//and so on ...
//You can add then one by one

[yourListObject addListItemObject:item1];
[yourListObject addListItemObject:item2];

//OR all at once
NSSet *itemsSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:item1,item2, nil];
[yourListObject addListItems: itemsSet];

//Save
NSError *saveError = nil;
[yourManagedContext save:&saveError];
```